# Passing generic type to object inside method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'd like to make my custom hook reusable as much as I can.

I'd like to pass generic type (cause for different forms I will have different errors fields) to my `const errors: Y = {};` which is empty now, but can be returned as object with validation errors.

In line 4 `const errors: Y = {};` I received an error:

> Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Y'.
> 'Y' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{}'.ts(2322)

[CODESANDBOX DEMO: HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-tf3g0?file=/src/validate.ts)

validate.ts:

```
export default function validate<T extends Record<string, string>, Y>(
  values: T
): Y {
  const errors: Y = {};

  if (!values.title) {
    errors.title = "Title is required";
  }

  return errors;
}
```

Place where I use `validate` method:

```
setErrors(validate<T, Y>(state));
```

```
function useFormState<T extends Record<string, string>, Y>(
  initialValue: T,
  initialErrors: Y
) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
    (prevState: T, { name, value }: InputChangeEvent["target"]) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value
    }),
    initialValue
  );

  const [errors, setErrors] = useState<Y>(initialErrors);

  const handleSubmit = (evt: FormEvent) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    setErrors(validate<T, Y>(state));
  };

  return [state, errors, handleSubmit] as const;
}

export default useFormState;
```

I tried to pass different type to this method `const errors: ErrorValues = {};` But then I have two different issues:

1. My method is not reusable, cause I cannot use it with different form.
2. When I want to call `setErrors(validate(state));` I received an another error:

> Argument of type 'ErrorValues' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction'.
> Type 'ErrorValues' is not assignable to type '(prevState: Y) => Y'.
> Type 'ErrorValues' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: Y): Y'.ts(2345)

Comment: You need to add a "condition" (using `extends`) for Y as well, to make it compatible with `{}`, probably sth like `Y extends Record<string, string?>`.

Comment: Unfortunetly it doesn't work. I was thinking about it, but my `ErrorValues` type has only optional values (so empty object should be valid to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this maybe ?
Have past this code temporary in your sandbox, seems ok

```
export default function validate<
  T extends Record<string, string>,
  Y extends Record<string, unkown>
>(values: T): Y {
  let errors: Y = {} as Y;

  if (!values.title) {
    errors = {
      ...errors,
      title: "Title is required ",
    };
  }

  return errors;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but only when I define `errors` as `let`, and then in every if I have to use spread operator and build new `errors` object. Do you know how to do that using `errors.foo = "bar"`?

Comment: why do you want to define errors as `const` as you will modify it later on ? And spread operator is the best solution to add key/value pairs"on the fly". You can not use `errors.foo = "bar"` in your case, because foo is not implementing a type or interface tat contains `foo` key.

Comment: Of course I meant `errors.title = "smth"`, I wrote `errors.foo = bar` as an example.